# ubuntu 20.04 cannot hibernate and stuck in loop

Tags: hibernate

recently installed Ubuntu on my Laptop ...every thing is pretty smooth but every time i use `systemctl hibernate` it fails and keeps laptop on until the battery runs out(and the screen goes of so i cant really tell what going on).
and i don't have much information to tell where the problem is coming from(i don't know where log file is (to be more accurate))tried searching in the web and everyone issue was resuming from hibernate not hibernating the device
also set my swap size almost twice my RAM size(RAM:12GB , SWAP:23GB)and its not working yet...i guess its not related to swap size.
anyone knows how to solve this ?

Comment: Hibernate does not always work well; will depend on computer specifications.

Comment: Is there a way to find out that hibernation will or wont work on my laptop?

Comment: For your question, it seems you already found out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found an answer :
after a new installation - of another distro - i used a swap file instead of a swap partition; and hibernation worked!

in other words, if your hibernation does not work, try swap file instead of swap partition.